# Call function onClick ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, onclick

I have a dropdown menu that show a list of files saved on disk:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It works fine but when you think about it, I have to load all the links/docs every time someone goes on the page.

What I would like to do is to have some sort of onClick function so that it would load / get the files only when asked so when I click on the 'a' tag.

I tried to add an `onclick="nameOfmyFunction"` but that does not work.

Could you give me some tips to achieve this? Or is it even possible?

Edit:
That is not it. I want to load al my files when I click on the "Consulter les conventions" which is the first `<a class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">`  tag.
So I tried something like this :

[image]
If the user click on the "conculter les conventions" then I load my files and create my dropdown menu else do not create the dropdown menu.
But I get the error that (when I try it) the function is not defined.

Comment: This tag <a> conflicts with the event (onclick="nameOfmyFunction"). It need to be changed to other tags. In addition, '@fileSubbed' generates a string with '\', cannot be passed to method nameOfmyFunction. So it need to change, such as: <span  onclick="nameOfmyFunction('\@fileSub')">@fileSub</span>

Comment: I added some things, because this is not this `<a>` tag that I want to use

Comment: The loadDocs in getDocs(loadDocs) is not parsed into a correct variable.

Comment: What do you mean ? My `loadDocs` variable is a `boolean` and I ask in my `getDocs(boolean)` to put the parameter to `True`

Comment: I simulated the click event locally, which can be triggered well. I do not know how you handle this event, it’s not showed in the code you gave.